# Load all property files with unknown names from a directory in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a Spring Boot (2.6.5) application that has a build in default property file (contained in the jar).
I also specify an external property file by using `--spring.config.additional-location=/data/config/myapp.properties`.

This works as expected, both files are loaded and properties of both files are used where the external pairs override the internal in the case of duplicate keys.

Now I want to split up the `myapp.properties` into multiple smaller property files. The reason for this is that they are created by a Kubernetes configMap, and some parts are used in multiple applications, so it makes sense to split those in smaller files instead of duplicating everything.

I tried to set the parameter to a directory, like `--spring.config.additional-location=/data/config/` and then placing the various `.properties` files in this directory. However, when I do this, Spring will no longer load the files. So it seems that when I don't specify a specific filename, it only scans for `application.properties`.

How can I configure Spring to look for and load **all** files of type `.properties` in the given directory? I could specify each file individually,  but that would require me to always keep track of the files that are present which is difficult to maintain.

Comment: You'll probably have to [find](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))
 them

Comment: Since the properties are stored in Kubernetes ConfigMaps, another option would be to use configuration trees instead of properties files: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.configtree. The `configtree:` feature was designed for just such a use case.

Comment: @ScottFrederick could you add that as an actual answer, as it solves the issue in the most clean way I think.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [features.external-config.files.wildcard-locations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.wildcard-locations)

In your case if you use `--spring.config.additional-location=file:data/config/*/` then the files like `data/config/first/application.properties` and `data/config/second/application.properties` will be loaded.

*Note*: If you have a different config.name, like `--spring.config.name=myapp`
then all the directories should contain `myapp.properties`